# .NET File Sync Library

Tags: .net, synchronization

Is there a good .NET file syncing library?  It can be pretty basic and only needs to work on local and mapped drives (no server client model like rsync is needed).

And yes, I know there is the MS Sync Services, but that is *a lot* more than what I need.

Comment: did you have to roll your own in the end?

Comment: pretty sure I did, but that is a long forgotten project at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put something together yourself based on the FileSystemWatcher component, or are you looking for something more complete?

Comment: I had an interesting problem with FileSystemWatchers when I tried to use them on a networked drive.  When the network connection got temporarily hosed up, the FileSystemWatcher on the remote directory stopped working and wouldn't once the network connection was restored.

Comment: Yeah, looking for something more complete.

Answer (score 2):

There is also Microsoft's [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx). [SyncToy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy) is actually using the sync framework to implement it's functionality. Here are some of the APIs:

- [Microsoft.Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.aspx)
- [Microsoft.Synchronization.Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.files.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's SyncToy tool installs an API that you can call from your code, according to the article at:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/SyncToy_Helper.aspx